# Unity3D OSX Webview Plugin

Tags: macos, web, webview, unity-game-engine

I unsuccessfully searching for Unity3D plugin what implement WebViews for OS X and (optional) iOS, which contains events (such as page load complete, process link etc.).
I have tried:

- uniwebview.onevcat.com (only mobile platforms)
- https://github.com/gree/unity-webview (no events)
- awesomium.com (it is good, but very hard for commercial use)

May be is exist another appropriate solutions?

Answer (score 0):

uWebKit is an HTML5 WebView for Unity Pro on Windows and OSX: http://uwebkit.com/